# Insert data to table with existing data, then delete data that was not touched during session

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert, database-replication

I am making bunch of `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to a table filled with data.

I need to fill table with that data AND remove data that I haven't filled (I mean remove rows that was not mentioned in my `INSERTs`).

What I tried and what was working:

> 1. create new timestamp column in table
> 2. During INSERTs insert or update this column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so that all rows I touched have newest timestamps
> 3. Run delete query that deletes all rows that are older than the starting time of my script.

This idea works perfectly, but there is one problem: my replication binary log get filled with unnececary data on both modes (ROW and STATEMENT). I don't need that timestamps at all to be replicated...

I don't want to do `TRUNCATE TABLE` before inserts because my app should deliever a non-stop access to data (old or new). If I do `TRUNCATE TABLE` tables can be without data for some time.

I can also save all primary key values that I insert in scripts memory or temporary table, and then delete the rows that are not in that table, but I hope there is a more optimized and clever way to do that.

Do you have any idea how can I achieve that goal so I can update data, delete only untouched rows and replicate only changes (I guess in ROW mode)?

Comment: Edit your question and provide more details about the use case.  How much data are you replacing?  Can the application use "partial" data, from before and after the update?  How many of the columns are being modified? The `truncate table` approach seems like the right approach under most circumstances, so it would be nice to know why it doesn't work in your case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The case is written in my question: because I should deleiver a non-stop access to data, no matter is it old or new, that's why. If truncate table is replicated and then the connection drops slave tables would be empty. This is not good at all. I don't want tables to be empty at any time.

Comment: . . You have other considerations (such as replication) which are only alluded to and haven't provided any sizing.  My best guess is that a solution using partitions is probably the best for your problem.  You will still have a "hiccup" for adding and dropping a partition, but that should be small overhead and independent of the size of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with replication binary logs, sorry in advance if won't work. I assumed that logging can be set differently for tables.

I would do the following:

- create a table for the new data with the same primary key column with
  the old table
- delete all rows from old table where not found in the new table
- update rows in the old table according to the new table

This way wouldn't be unnecessary log inserts.
This assumes that you have the required space in the server, but can work.